# Unable to connect to TFS server from eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, tfs, azure-devops

I am trying to connect to my personal Azure DevOps organization from eclipse IDE.

I clicked on OK and copied the device code and added it to Microsoft.com/devicelogin. still, it didn't work.
I have also tried entering credentials in the enter credentials section. still, it did not work. It just shows an authorization error and then exits.

[image]

Comment: Did you tried using Personal access token as credentials? Have you tried reinstall Team Explorer everywhere?